# SSH : Could not resolve hostname 192.168.40.250:2080, Name or service not known

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I just installed a centOS 6.5 web server on a VMWare. Now I' like to access it from my physical computer in order to use the LAMP stack i installed on it to host a web application am developping.
But am faced with this error since;
Have read the other issues, but didn't find something as specific as this...
Can someone help me out of this?!

Comment: What command did you enter into command line? Standard port is 25 for SSH. Usually you do not have to specify a port number, unless you have specific port for it.

Comment: @kukulo The standard SSH port is 22. ;)

Answer (score 5):

`ssh` does not support `address:port` syntax; instead the port is specified using the `-p` option. So what you want is

```
ssh -p 2080 192.168.40.250
```

see also `man ssh`.

Comment: @RayannRodd, if that worked, please click the check mark to the left of the answer to accept it.